# web scraping complete data from all web pages in a website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

With this code I am able to get the data from first page of this website. But I want to get the data from complete. I want to extract the data from all the webpages. After extraction of data it sholud be either save in excel or csv file.

```
install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

pg<-read_html("https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidresultlists?bidresultlists&page_no=i")

#pg <- read_html("https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidresultlists")

blocks <- html_nodes(pg, ".block")

items_and_quantity <- html_nodes(blocks, xpath=".//div[@class='col-block' and contains(., 'Item(s)')]")

items <- html_nodes(items_and_quantity, xpath=".//strong[contains(., 'Item(s)')]/following-sibling::span") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)
quantity <- html_nodes(items_and_quantity, xpath=".//strong[contains(., 'Quantity')]/following-sibling::span") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE) %>% as.numeric()

department_name_and_address <- html_nodes(blocks, xpath=".//div[@class='col-block' and contains(., 'Department Name And Address')]") %>% 
  html_text(trim=TRUE) %>% 
  gsub("\n", "|", .) %>% 
  gsub("[[:space:]]*\\||\\|[[:space:]]*", "|", .)

block_header <- html_nodes(blocks, "div.block_header")

html_nodes(block_header, xpath=".//p[contains(@class, 'bid_no')]") %>%
  html_text(trim=TRUE) %>% 
  gsub("^.*: ", "", .) -> bid_no

html_nodes(block_header, xpath=".//p/b[contains(., 'Status')]/following-sibling::span") %>% 
  html_text(trim=TRUE) -> status

html_nodes(blocks, xpath=".//strong[contains(., 'Start Date')]/following-sibling::span") %>%
  html_text(trim=TRUE) -> start_date

html_nodes(blocks, xpath=".//strong[contains(., 'End Date')]/following-sibling::span") %>%
  html_text(trim=TRUE) -> end_date

data.frame(
  bid_no,
  status,
  start_date,
  end_date,
  items,
  quantity,
  department_name_and_address,
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
) -> xdf

xdf$is_ra <- grepl("/RA/", bid_no)

str(xdf)
## 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  8 variables:
##  $ bid_no                     : chr  "GEM/2018/B/93066" "GEM/2018/B/93082" "GEM/2018/B/93105" "GEM/2018/B/93999" ...
##  $ status                     : chr  "Not Evaluated" "Not Evaluated" "Not Evaluated" "Not Evaluated" ...
##  $ start_date                 : chr  "25-09-2018 03:53:pm" "27-09-2018 09:16:am" "25-09-2018 05:08:pm" "26-09-2018 05:21:pm" ...
##  $ end_date                   : chr  "18-10-2018 03:00:pm" "18-10-2018 03:00:pm" "18-10-2018 03:00:pm" "18-10-2018 03:00:pm" ...
##  $ items                      : chr  "automotive chassis fitted with engine" "automotive chassis fitted with engine" "automotive chassis fitted with engine" "Storage System" ...
##  $ quantity                   : num  1 1 1 2 90 1 981 6 4 376
##  $ department_name_and_address: chr  "Department Name And Address:||Ministry Of Steel Na Kirandul Complex N/a" "Department Name And Address:||Ministry Of Steel Na Kirandul Complex N/a" "Department Name And Address:||Ministry Of Steel Na Kirandul Complex N/a" "Department Name And Address:||Maharashtra Energy Department Maharashtra Bhusawal Tps N/a" ...
##  $ is_ra                      : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...

xdf
write.csv(xdf,'xdf1.csv')


write.csv(xdf,'xdf.csv')
write.csv(xdf,'xdf.csv', append = TRUE)
?write.csv

write.table( xdf1,  
             file="xdf.csv", 
             append = T, 
             sep=',', 
             row.names=F, 
             col.names=F )
```

Comment: Two questions. (1) You need to have a list or vector of URLs to crawl. Do you have that already or do you need to generate that? (2) Should the final result be in a single table or do you want a separate table per page?

Comment: no i want the result in single table

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

pg<-read_html("https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidresultlists?bidresultlists&page_no=1")

##Find total number of pages

page_num<-pg%>%
  html_nodes(".pagination")%>%
  html_nodes("li")%>%
  html_nodes("a")%>%
  .[5]%>%
  html_attrs()%>%
  unlist()%>%
  parse_number()%>%unique()

 #make function for scraping page
scr=function(i){
  pg<-read_html(paste0("https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidresultlists?bidresultlists&page_no=",i))
  blocks <- html_nodes(pg, ".block")

  items_and_quantity <- html_nodes(blocks, xpath=".//div[@class='col-block' and contains(., 'Item(s)')]")

  items <- html_nodes(items_and_quantity, xpath=".//strong[contains(., 'Item(s)')]/following-sibling::span") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)
  quantity <- html_nodes(items_and_quantity, xpath=".//strong[contains(., 'Quantity')]/following-sibling::span") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE) %>% as.numeric()

  department_name_and_address <- html_nodes(blocks, xpath=".//div[@class='col-block' and contains(., 'Department Name And Address')]") %>% 
    html_text(trim=TRUE) %>% 
    gsub("\n", "|", .) %>% 
    gsub("[[:space:]]*\\||\\|[[:space:]]*", "|", .)

  block_header <- html_nodes(blocks, "div.block_header")

  html_nodes(block_header, xpath=".//p[contains(@class, 'bid_no')]") %>%
    html_text(trim=TRUE) %>% 
    gsub("^.*: ", "", .) -> bid_no

  html_nodes(block_header, xpath=".//p/b[contains(., 'Status')]/following-sibling::span") %>% 
    html_text(trim=TRUE) -> status

  html_nodes(blocks, xpath=".//strong[contains(., 'Start Date')]/following-sibling::span") %>%
    html_text(trim=TRUE) -> start_date

  html_nodes(blocks, xpath=".//strong[contains(., 'End Date')]/following-sibling::span") %>%
    html_text(trim=TRUE) -> end_date

  data.frame(
    bid_no,
    status,
    start_date,
    end_date,
    items,
    quantity,
    department_name_and_address,
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
  ) -> xdf
  xdf$is_ra <- grepl("/RA/", bid_no)
  return(xdf)
}
#run for-loop for each page and save it in data frame  
res<-1:page_num%>%
  map_df(.,scr)

#for example 
1:2%>%
   map_df(.,scr)%>%
   head(5)
            bid_no               status          start_date            end_date                                                   items quantity
1 GEM/2018/B/94492        Not Evaluated 02-10-2018 10:42:am 22-10-2018 01:00:pm door frame metal detector dfmd  security metal detector        1
2 GEM/2018/B/95678        Not Evaluated 29-09-2018 11:01:am 22-10-2018 01:00:pm                                         Foolscap sheets      100
3 GEM/2018/B/96187        Not Evaluated 01-10-2018 10:29:am 22-10-2018 01:00:pm                               OEM Cartridge/ Consumable       20
4 GEM/2018/B/96196        Not Evaluated 01-10-2018 10:48:am 22-10-2018 01:00:pm                               OEM Cartridge/ Consumable       20
5 GEM/2018/B/96722 Technical Evaluation 01-10-2018 05:26:pm 22-10-2018 01:00:pm        Special Purpose Telephones(smart phone for ICDS)    33914
                                                                                          department_name_and_address is_ra
1 Department Name And Address:||Ministry Of Shipping Na Electronics Directorate General Of Lighthouses And Lightships FALSE
2                            Department Name And Address:||Ministry Of Defence Department Of Defence Cweafborjhar N/a FALSE
3                            Department Name And Address:||Ministry Of Defence Department Of Defence Cweafborjhar N/a FALSE
4                            Department Name And Address:||Ministry Of Defence Department Of Defence Cweafborjhar N/a FALSE
5                                 Department Name And Address:||Bihar Social Welfare Department Bihar Procurement N/a FALSE
```

Comment: no, u must enter only first page, after that script find number of page and scrap that all in for-loop

Comment: looks like your scraping code not ideal :) I just put it together

Comment: it's strange, I scaped `res<-1:15%>%map_df(.,scr)` 15 pages and 150 records with this script 2 min ago